# How to create multiple BI publisher reports from same ess job in oracle cloud

Tags: bi-publisher, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to run a ESS job that will create two files as output. My requirement is to create an extract file and another file that shows how many records are present in the extract file. I know how to create the extract file by writing the select query , but how do I find the count in the first select query and send it to another file ? These two files should be generated when I run the same ess job.
One report should be created after another

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it, I believe that this document going over creating reports in BI can assist - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22257/create_rpt_jobs.htm#BIPUG188

Specifically section 4.3